# How to show a preview image while Flash SWF is loading?

Tags: image, flash, preview, preloader

I have some 3rd party Flash SWFs on my site that are up to 100KB in size. e.g. the Flash video player "JWPlayer" SWF is 98KB.

That's fine for people with Broadband, but not so good for the slow dial up bandwidth visitors. e.g at 40 kbits/s, we're talking 20 seconds to download.

The problem is that on slow connections, all the visitors are seeing is a static white screen, and so may close the page thinking it's dead. If I right click the area where the SWF is to go, an Adobe Flash Player Object is occupying the space, but the 3rd party SWF has not finished loading in yet.

I would like the website visitors to see a loading spinner GIF or something similar.

Unfortunately, none of the 3rd party SWFs have "preloader" element. And they are not open source, so I cannot add a preloader to them.

So, my question is...

Is there any way to display a loading image, prefereably a GIF animation, while the SWF is loading?

For example, is there any way to force the Adobe Flash Player to show an image while it is loading in the SWF?

I don't have any Flash coding skills, so a solution that doesn't include creating an extra SWF or a SWF within a SWF would, probably isn't best for me, but might be worth adding to the post in case other people have a similar problem.

I am using swfobject 2.2 to embed the SWFs, so a solution that takes that into account or at least doesn't break that would help.

Thanks very much for taking the time to read my post, even if you can't help.

Dave

Comment: I thought about using jquery to add the image using a CSS z-index in front of the Flash object, then use the swfobject  callbackFunction to remove it once the SWF has loaded. I have done this in the past to put a Logo in front of the SWF. But this involved playing around with the "wmode" parameter of the flash object, & there were issues that may or may not have been resolved to do with Flash and the wmode parameter. I don't recall if the issue was to do with what the Flash version, or what browser, but it was enough to stop me using this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we decided to go for a mixed setup:

For users with low bandwidth, we set the flash parameter wmode to "transparent", and set the gif to be a background image (without a loading spinner these low bandwidth users think the page is doing nothing).

However, using wmode = transparent has a negative side effect in that that Flash won't use Hardware Acceleration. But for our low bandwidth users, the bitrates of e.g. our video are low enough that in most cases they don't really need Hardware Acceleration.

For high bandwidth users, we deliver e.g. higher bitrate video, and so Hardware Acceleration becomes more important. For these users we use wmode = direct, and do without a loading spinner GIF as the SWF loads quickly enough anyhow.

With the size of our SWF files and their XML files that must also be loaded, we have gone for a limit of 1 megabit bandwidth, where if users have a higher bandwidth we don't use a loading graphic, and visa versa. Other people may find other levels more suitable.

We'd prefer to be able to set the bandwidth limit a lot lower if possible, as on older PCs we could do with some Harware Acceleration of video that is 384 kbit/s, but removing the loading spinner of a user with a low bandwidth like that would mean them waiting too long with nothing happpening on the screen, and this seems worse than losing a few frames during video playback.

Here is a link to Adobe's description of the various wmodes and how different browsers handle them.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html#main_BrowserSupportForWmodes

Hope this helps someone else someday.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which 3rd party swfs you're using it could be tough, but here's a few things to think about:

One approach would be to hide the swf (or the div that the swf is inside) until it's loaded, and then reveal it once it's finished. You can have a spinner / loading image sit in it's place in the mean time. That said, what you really need is a javascript function that gets called once the load is complete. Once this happens, you can use jQuery to `.show()` or `.hide()` your spinner and swf respectively.

JWPlayer has some [events that you can make use of](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference#Events). It looks like `onReady` would do the trick for you.

As for the other 3rd party swfs, I'd look around their documentation for similar javascript callbacks.  I know the [swfobject has an onLoad callback](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api), as do a few other embed solutions like [Swiff](http://www.mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/Swiff), assuming you can use them.

Good luck!

EDIT: The swfobject's callback might be called when the swf has successfully been *embedded* not necessarily *loaded*. Your best bet is to play around with this and see if it works - or use the 3rd party swf's callback functions wherever possible.

EDIT 2: Here's a flash loader example.

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;

function startLoad() {
    var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("url-to-your-swf.swf");
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
    mLoader.load(mRequest);
}

function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event){
    addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
    //Here's where you specify your js function
    ExternalInterface.call("flashLoaded"); // <-- where 'flashloaded' is a js function

}

startLoad();
```

Comment: Hi Chazbot. I've had a go with your suggestion. Firstly, your EDIT seems correct. It seems that as soon as the OBJECT gets created on the page (which holds the Adobe Flash Player), swfobject fires its callbackFunction. i.e. it fires before the swf has loaded, and so I can't use this callbackFunction. So, I've managed to find onReady events for each of the 3rd party swf's and had a go with these.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that using jquery's hide() function, essentially does a CSS display:none, and it turns out that this stops or blocks the flash object. The onReady events never fire. Reading around on the net it seems this may even be by design. The following post suggests instead of using a display:none, you can set a div that contains the flash object to CSS width:1px; height 1px; overflow:hidden .... http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/04/14/load-flash-swf-in-hidden-div/ .... and then when the onReady event fires, set the size back up to full size.

Comment: Although, this approach has succesfully allowed my to display a loading image while the swf is loading, it has an unforseen consequence in that for users who are using the Firefox Flashblock plugin (which stops any Flash playing until you press the Flashblock play button), they don't see the Flashblock play button as it is inside the div that is 1px by 1px. This means for these users it just looks like the page is broken.

Comment: Hmmm... well I'm sorry this workaround doesn't fit your needs. The only other solution I can think of is to look into creating a container swf that loads the subsequent swfs, and shows a preloader graphic in there. I recognize that you're trying to avoid AS3 work, but under these unique circumstances it seems like the best option, provided you can load your 3rd party swfs into a parent swf.

Comment: edited post to show aforementioned flash loader - hope this helps dude!